# `oc cluster up` fails during initial startup

Tags: openshift-origin, okd

I am trying out okd but it fails for me during the oc cluster up port check step. The debug output is not very verbose to be polite. Do you have an idea what to look for.

```
$ oc cluster up
Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 is available ...
Checking type of volume mount ...
Determining server IP ...
Checking if OpenShift is already running ...
Checking for supported Docker version (=>1.22) ...
Checking if insecured registry is configured properly in Docker ...
Checking if required ports are available ...
error: a port needed by OpenShift is not available
```

But the required ports 53 and 8443 are not taken

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep '\(:8443\|:53\)'
```

At least `netstat` returns nothing

Versions:

```
$ oc version
oc v3.11.0+0cbc58b
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO
```

and

```
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

I have not been able to find out how to turn debugging on so that it is possible to see what it really checks for.

Comment: Here's a list of required ports: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/prerequisites.html#required-ports . I'm trying to figure this out too.

Answer (score 0):

Has the user you are running the command as enough priveledges to open privileged ports (ports <1024) on your host machine?

try running cluster up as root or with sudo

Answer (score -1):

yes I starting whole okd as root user